# need access to xml data but unsure where to build function

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have a course built in Lectora and I am trying to create an efficient way to store transcripts for each page of the course. Whenever a page from the course loads, a flash command is directed to a swf file along with a unique pageID. and a string (containing the appropriate transcript) is returned.

Here is a short version of my xml file `transcripts.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <transcripts>
    <transcriptText pageID="c1p1">Transcript 1 text</transcriptText>
    <transcriptText pageID="c1p2">Transcript 2 text</transcriptText>
    <transcriptText pageID="c1p3">Transcript 3 text</transcriptText>
    <transcriptText pageID="c1p4">Transcript 4 text</transcriptText>
  </transcripts>
```

I am using the following XmlLoader.as file (which I found on the exchange, thank you) to load the xml.

```
package {

import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;

public class XmlLoader extends EventDispatcher {

    private var _xml:XML;

     public function XmlLoader(xmlPath:String){
        var xmlUrlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlPath);
        var xmlUrlLoader:URLLoader =  new URLLoader(xmlUrlRequest);
        xmlUrlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
    }

    private function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void{
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
        _xml = new XML(e.currentTarget.data);
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
    }

    public function getXml():XML{
        return this._xml;
    }

}

}
```

And below is the code I have on the first frame of the flash file.

```
var myXML:XML;
var menuXmlList:XmlLoader = new XmlLoader("transcripts.xml");
menuXmlList.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e: Event):void
 {
    myXML = (e.currentTarget.getXml());
 }

// this function is called as a Flash Command from within
// the course each time a new page loads. pageID is the unique
// identifier for that particular page.

function getTranscript(pageID: String):String
 {
    var pageNumber: String = pageID;
    var transcript: String = myXML.transcriptText.(@pageID == pageNumber);
    return (transcript);
 }

ExternalInterface.addCallback("getTranscript", getTranscript);
```

I have researched this a bit over the past few days and come to understand some of what is going on. The nature of asynchronous code means that the xml data hasn't made its way into `myXML` when `getTranscripts()` is called so trying to access `myXML` yields null and null reference warnings.

I think I need to hold the xml data in the class file until `getTranscripts` needs it. But I am not sure how to go about this. I've tried to write additional functions in the `XmlLoader.as` file but haven't met with any success.

Can anyone tell me if I am on the right track? Is the correct approach to create a method(s) in `XmlLoader.as` file that can be called by`getTranscripts()` to return this value: `myXML.transcriptText.(@pageID == pageNumber)` pageNumber (being the unique identifier)?

Any thoughts or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

regards

Comment: actionscript 3 is asynchronous that you know. so it works by listening to events like COMPLETE. You can access the data on COMPLETE callback and make it available for ExternalInterface then after.